# getDrawingCache causes app to freeze

Tags: android

My app is currently freezing on initialization. I have narrowed it down to something related to the `getDrawingCache()` call in this snippet.. when I take it out, the problem disappears.

```
public Shot getScreenshot(View view) throws DrawingCacheException {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        Bitmap drawingCache = view.getDrawingCache();
        if (drawingCache == null) {
            throw new DrawingCacheException("Cannot get bitmap drawing cache");
        }

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingCache);
    } finally {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }
    //do postprocessing
}
```

The problem is certainly something with the context. This was previously working, and I haven't touched this code at all, but I did refactor the class that called it.

And before anyone mentions it, yes, this is running on the activity's UI thread. I've quadruple-checked.

So, what could be interacting with this code to cause the freeze?

Comment: Check what it is doing in the DDMS thread view http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#thread

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the screenshotting, together with the encoding afterwards, was so slow that it was freezing the app. It was not happening very often, but increasing the delay fixed the problem. Time to work on perf!

Comment: which delay you are talking about? @james-koppel